# Unable to read and print yaml file data

Tags: go

Language: Go

I am practicing how to read and print the yaml file data but unable to do so and the code is getting through. Can someone help here?

**Yaml file:**

```
ENV:
 foo: test
 boo: test-123-tet222
```

**code:**

```
package test

import (
    "testing"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type config struct {
    foo string 
    boo string 
}


func TestTerraformAzureCosmosDBExample(t *testing.T) {
 yFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yaml")
 if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
 }

 data := make(map[string]config)

 err2 := yaml.Unmarshal(yFile, &data)
 if err2 != nil {
      log.Fatal(err2)
 }
 for k, v := range data {
      fmt.Printf(k, v)
 }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 foo: test
 boo: test-123-tet222
```

**Actual Output:**

```
C:\foo\boo>go test -v
=== RUN   TestTerraformAzureCosmosDBExample
ENV%!(EXTRA test.config={ })--- PASS: TestTerraformAzureCosmosDBExample (0.00s)
PASS
ok      foobo_test   0.179s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `config` struct is missing yaml tags. Edit it as follows. Also the `Printf` method expects a formatter string, edit that too as follows.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "testing"
)

type config struct {
    Foo string `yaml:"foo"`
    Boo string `yaml:"boo"`
}


func TestTerraformAzureCosmosDBExample(t *testing.T) {
    yFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    data := make(map[string]config)

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yFile, &data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for k, v := range data {
        fmt.Printf(`key: %v, value: %v`, k,v)
    }
}
```

gives the output:

```
key: ENV, value: {test test-123-tet222}--- PASS: TestTerraformAzureCosmosDBExample (0.00s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over `data` that is a `map[string]config`.

That object has one key, `ENV` and the value for that key is the `config` object you are looking for.

Try with:

```golang
fmt.Printf("Foo: %S\n", data["ENV"].Foo)
fmt.Printf("Boo: %S\n", data["ENV"].Boo)
```

Comment: Getting following error "cannot range over data["ENV"] (type config)"

Comment: yes, correct as that's not a map any more. Changed the answer